# using csvimpoter in django

Tags: django, csv, import

I want to import the entire csv file in a model without reading row by row from the file.Please help me on this by providing a example model and a source code to import.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What other mechanisms are you expecting for reading the csv file, aside from row by row?

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening the file from disk, you can wrap your file object in django.core.files.File and pass it to the save method of the model field you're saving it to:

```
from django.core.files import File
csv_file = open("sample.csv", "rb")
csv_file = File(csv_file)
my_model_instance.my_file_field.save("sample.csv", csv_file)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/files/file/#additional-methods-on-files-attached-to-objects

If you're dealing with an uploaded file from request.FILES, you can assign it directly to your model instance's FileField:

```
my_model_instance.my_file = request.FILES["csvfile"]
my_model_instance.save()
```

Don't forget `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form or request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: i am uploading a file from the webpage and accessing it.Is it possible to use the given code for it?.Please explain